# Javascript or angularjs defer browser close or tab close between refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, event-handling, dom-events

Is there any way to trigger if the user refreshes the page or closes the browser / browser tab? (I'd like to trigger that in AngularJS / JavaScript). Any thoughts about this?

Right now I know only when the current page closes with the following code:

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
   var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compatable

   myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
       var confirmationMessage = ' ';  // a space
       (e || window.event).returnValue = "Are you sure that you'd like to close the browser?";
       return confirmationMessage;
   });
```

Comment: write one directive.. put this code inside directive..inject `$window` dependancy and use it instead of `window`

Comment: @pankajparkar: Thanks! is there any chance to give me a small example? Would help me to learn it faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive may look like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return function($window) {
        var myEvent = $window.attachEvent || $window.addEventListener,
            chkevent = $window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; 

        myEvent(chkevent, function(e) {
            var confirmationMessage = ' ';
            (e || $window.event).returnValue = "Are you sure that you'd like to close the browser?";
            return confirmationMessage;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind event in `link` function which will give access to angular compiled directive element.

**Directive**

```
.directive('windowExit', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(element, attrs){
       var myEvent = $window.attachEvent || $window.addEventListener,
       chkevent = $window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compatable

       myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
           var confirmationMessage = ' ';  // a space
           (e || $window.event).returnValue = "Are you sure that you'd like to close the browser?";
           return confirmationMessage;
       });
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body window-exit></body>
```

Comment: according to your answer I think it should be: `restrict: 'A'`, right?

Comment: It works for triggering only the close. But I'd like to make a difference when it closes and when it refreshes the page.

Comment: Refresh in the sense..url hash change or else?

Comment: in the sense that it will refresh by pressing the refresh button from the browser or just using keyboard shortcuts

Comment: try `myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
   // Firefox || IE
   e = e || window.event;
   var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
    
   if(y < 0)  
   e.returnValue = "Are you sure that you'd like to close the browser?";
   else 
   e.returnValue = "Window refreshed";
     return confirmationMessage;
    });` atleast work for mouse

Comment: yup, seems a dead end for me. What I actually try to achieve is when the user closes the browser to remove some cookies that I've added. But I'd like to avoid that on refresh. I've tried any option that came into my mind.

Comment: well, I just found a solution. I'll switch it to localStorage; that is what I actually need. If I close the window then everything goes away. I'll share my final code soon.

Comment: are you doing it by check `window.history`?

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up by using this approach:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$state', '$window', '$timeout', '$sce', 'UserAuthorize', function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $state, $window, $timeout, $sce, UserAuthorize) {

//Getting the value from storage
$window.sessionStorage.getItem('key');

//Setting the value to storage
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Remove from storage
$window.sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

}]);
```

Based on this I've saved my values when the user was logged in. Then when the browser window was closed, the values will not persist.

By using the local storage I was able to persist the session only for current window.

EDIT:
I though by using cookie approach I could handle that but then I got into the issue with differentiating refresh and close. It turned out that localStorage saved my day :)